# How to recursively delete files using regular expressions on OSx

Tags: terminal, rm

I want to delete all the temp files under a specific directory and all its subdirectories. I can search for the files using the command `find ./* -iname "._*"` but how do I delete all these files? I know `-iname` is not working with `rm` and `rm */._*` didn't really work as I was expecting

Answer (score 2):

Your specific find

```
find ./* -iname '._*' -delete
```

a more general example (delete all .orig files after a git merge);

```
find . -name '*.orig' -type f -delete
```